# Android epoch wrong time

Tags: android, date, epoch

By using the below code i get 43753-07-31T04:40:44-0500

```
long installed = 1318562444444;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(installed * 1000L));
```

HELP :(

Comment: What should be the exact output?

Comment: PS: Are you asking a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed is already in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");